# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with this error in my query:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

I've been trying to fix it for 2 days but I can't fix it. I am searching for a solution but I can't find one

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "user");
          $db = mysql_select_db("game", $conn);
          $s_ip = mysql_real_escape_string("{$server['b']['ip']}");
          $s_port = mysql_real_escape_string("{$server['b']['q_port']}");
          $s_map = mysql_real_escape_string("{$server['s']['map']}");
          $s_minplayers = mysql_real_escape_string("{$server['s']['players']}");
          $s_maxplayers = mysql_real_escape_string("{$server['s']['playersmax']}");
          $s_name = mysql_real_escape_string("{$misc['name_filtered']}");
          $s_status = mysql_real_escape_string("{$misc['text_status']}");
          $s_game = mysql_real_escape_string("{$server['b']['type']}");
          $query = "SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE ip = '$ip1' AND port = '$port1'";
          $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
          if ($result == 1){
          $query_update = "UPDATE `servers`
    SET name='$s_name', ip='$s_ip', port='$s_port', max_players='$s_maxplayers', min_players='$s_minplayers', map='$s_map', s_status='$s_status', game='$s_game'  
    WHERE ip='$s_ip', port='$s_port'";
    $result_update = mysql_query($query_update) or die(mysql_error());
          } else {
          $query_insert = "INSERT INTO `servers` (id, name, ip, port, max_players, min_players, map, s_status, game, s_user, community, clan)
    VALUES ('', $s_name, $s_ip, $s_port, $s_maxplayers, $s_minplayers, $s_map, $s_status, $s_game, '', '', '')";
    $result_insert = mysql_query($query_insert) or die(mysql_error()); }
```

Comment: Which query is failing?

Comment: Strings need to be wrapped in quotes in mysql queries

Comment: Quote your values `VALUES ('', $s_name, $s_ip, $s_port, $s_maxplayers, $s_minplayers, $s_map, $s_status, $s_game, '', '', '')` for the variables. You've done it for the other one, so do it for this one as well.

Comment: As an aside: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: and/or `WHERE ip='$s_ip' and port='$s_port'";` you can swap `and` for `or` depending on the condition.

Comment: @Strawberry `OR` might get jealous.

Comment: Why are you doing `m_r_e_s("{$server['b']['ip']}")`?  You don't need the quotes or `{}` there, just do `m_r_e_s($server['b']['ip'])`.  P.S. Please look into prepared statements and upgrading to MySQLi/PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP variables in your query should be surrounded by quotes, for example `'$s_name'` instead of `$s_name`, like how you did in your `query_update`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that's all that's wrong with OP's code?

Comment: True, yet that's the first gauntlet.

Comment: For the WHERE clause, I usually use keyword 'AND' to specify two clauses on the WHERE. I've never tried it with a comma, not sure if it will work.

Comment: The comma does not work for a WHERE clause. [**Check out the syntax**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/) - Using commas as seperators is correct for `SET` though.